# HERE Maps Satellite Tiles not showing address on the Map like BING Maps Do

Tags: maps, bing-maps, here-maps-rest

In the BING maps, the ‘Aerial’ view used to show the satellite view. In the HERE maps, the ‘Aerial’ view shows the satellite view too but not showing addresses. See example below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the **Hybrid** map view option and its close enough to the BING satellite view:

[image]